# Activation of Windows 10 Enterprise

Tags: windows, license

for a couple of months I have a PC with Windows 10 Enterprise evaluation installed (the only version available on the Microsoft website).
I would like to purchase a license of Windows 10 Pro and activate it in the evaluation Windows installation, unfortunately, however, Microsoft assistance did not give me convincing answers regarding the feasibility of this operation.
Of course, the question is also in the case of a Windows evaluation server.
I think by installing the activation license for Windows 10 Pro, Windows 10 Enterprise magically switches to Windows 10 Pro, but I have serious doubts ...
Has anyone had any experience with this?

Thank you

Max

Comment: pro license will not work for enterprise versions.

Comment: You cannot downgrade from Enterprise to Professional without reinstalling Windows. Even if you had a license for Windows 10 Enterprise you wouldn't be able to activate the evaluation installation you have.